# How to replace this pattern with a functional alternative?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following pattern in Scala:

```
object CurrentDriver {

  private var webDriver: WebDriver = null

  def invalidate = {
    webDriver.quit()
    webDriver = null
  }

  def getWebDriver = {
    if (webDriver==null)
      webDriver = DriverFactory.buildWebDriver
    webDriver
  }
}
```

Its not functional, it has a var, and the invalidate method returns a Unit. The singleton object is needed as it's referred to by a few classes which are instantiated using reflection by a framework, so i have not way to pass arguments to them. Hence they need to call getWebDriver to get access to the same instance of the WebDriver. I need to periodically (after each test scenario, which consists of multiple test functions) quit and re-create a new WebDriver, which is handled by the invalidate method.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest something like an `around` block.

```
 object CurrentDriver {
      def around(f: WebDriver => Unit) = {
          val webDriver: WebDriver = DriverFactory.buildWebDriver
          f(webDriver) // your tests
          webDriver.quit()
      }
 }
```

For each of your tests blocks, you can combine the block with the `around` function.

For example:

```
 def testFunc(webDriver: WebDriver) = around{ 
   assert(2 ==2)
   // do something with webDriver
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but does not solve my particular problem as i need the same instance to be used for multiple tests, Its my fault as I didn't work the question correctly, I've updated the description. Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing the signature of tests will be same that is, each test will not take anything and return unit .. In that case the signature of around block can be list of functions rather than one function .. And the logic will remain the same ... In any case, having couple of vars for test is not so bad :)

Comment: I'm guessing the `webDriver` instance should also be passed to the `f` function, so the code in the `around` block has access to it.